# could different bloods of the same metal type mix?

Tags: science-based, metals, oxygen, blood

[Other blood colors](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/other-blood-colors)

The link about talks about other color's of blood that could be if made with either different metals or different oxygen carrier's. What I want to know is if you mixed iron blood with hemoglobin and iron blood with Chlorocruorin (or Hemerythrin), would that

A) create a negative reaction? (something bad happens)

B) Create a positive reaction? (something good happens) or

C) create a neutral reaction? (nothing happens like when you mix O-blood with AB-blood)

Another question, would there be a change to the O, AB, A, and B typing of blood?
what about the negative(-) or positive (+) typing of blood?

Why?

***Edit***

I know that some species [Chem of the blood](http://www.compoundchem.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Chemistry-of-Blood-Colours-2015.png) can have two different oxygenates( i think that's the right word) in their system at the same time, why not humans?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: From your comments, it looks like you are infusing someone with a bag of blood.  Are you presuming from the start that the body's immune system doesn't freak the heck out about all of these foreign bodyies in the bloodstream?  The immune response would be where I'd focus, but it really depends on how fantastical your species are.  If they have the same blood in every way shape or form, except it was convenient to give them different oxygen carriers, then it would be like user 16295' answer

Answer (score 1):

You'd most likely end up with the same effect as either low haemoglobin or carbon monoxide poisoning. The person with the mixed blood would not get enough of their own blood type for their body chemistry and would suffer from oxygen starvation. There'd be no actual reaction between the bloods themselves.

---

The average person has around 5.5 litres of blood. Details of how much you can afford to lose

[Breaking Point: How Much Blood Can The Human Body Lose?](http://www.medicaldaily.com/breaking-point-how-much-blood-can-human-body-lose-350792)

> A Class 2 hemorrhage is a loss of 15 to 30 percent of blood volume. This is where symptoms of blood loss begin to manifest. “The body tries to compensate at this point with, among other things, a faster heartbeat to speed oxygen to tissues,” Alton said. “The patient will feel weak, appear pale, and skin will be cool.”

Though haemorrhage symptoms are not the ones you're going to get. You'll be looking at anaemia / CO poisoning symptoms.

From NHS choices:
[CO poisoning](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Carbon-monoxide-poisoning/Pages/Symptoms.aspx)

```
headache
nausea (feeling sick) and vomiting
dizziness
tiredness and confusion
stomach pain
shortness of breath and difficulty breathing
```

[Iron deficiency anaemia](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Anaemia-iron-deficiency-/Pages/Symptoms.aspx)

```
tiredness and lethargy (lack of energy)
shortness of breath
heart palpitations (noticeable heartbeats)
a pale complexion
```

Note that they're much the same. They're both fundamentally oxygen starvation, though one is chronic and the other acute.

[One European standard blood bag: 600ml (pdf)](http://www.msssi.gob.es/profesionales/saludPublica/medicinaTransfusional/congresos/docs/eurobloodpack.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can i get more of the why? the human body has around 10 litres of blood, if you only got one bag of blood(how many litres is it?) would that cause problems? how much blood do you need to get be for problems arise?

Comment: Updated somewhat