# Golden blood of the Gods, How does it work biologically?

Tags: biology, gods, blood, biochemistry

In movies, novels, fictions and mythologies, it is quite often told/seen/heard that the blood of the gods are that of gold.

I want to know how does gold colored blood works in biology, what are its chemical compositions, what makes it gold?

Comment: Ummmm... magic. It's just magic. Asking what it would be like in the real world is like asking what a diamond unicorn would be like in the real world and whether or not its shit would sparkle.

Comment: i'm asking how gold colored blood works in reality...

Comment: Well they are usually called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichor and not golden blood but they do function as a form of blood I guess? It would require some special chemicals and evolution in reality but I guess it's not impossible but implausible since we have blue blood from horseshoe crabs and invisible blood from insects.

Comment: @Sky Having taken blood from a locust, I assure you it is not invisible! That would have made the experiment very difficult! :-) I assume you mean transparent?

Comment: Color descriptions in myths can be quite fanciful, so golden doesn't necessarily mean that it looks like gold, it might just as well mean that it's yellow. And as such the blood could function with chlorocruorin or coboglobin instead of hemoglobin.

Comment: @DrBob arh pardon me, slight error there XD. That 333 reputation and 33 views tho

Comment: Oxygenated blood (bleeding or arteries) or de-oxygenated blood (veins)?  Note that we usually talk about red as the color of our blood, but it looks blue in our veins.

Comment: "I have this **magical creature**. How does its blood work, **a non-magical explanation please**". See the problem here @micovillena? The cake is eaten or it is not eaten... mutually exclusive conditions. Either these things are magical or they are not. If they are magical: there you go, that is your explanation... magic makes their blood work. If they are not magic, then they are not gods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### [Coboglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coboglobin)

Coboglobin is currently a synthetic protein that performs the same function as hemoglobin.  It uses Cobalt in place of the iron atoms.

> Blood of this type would be **amber yellow** in color when in the veins
>   while **uncoloured and clear** in the arteries.

Quoted from Jim2B on [Other blood colors](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/other-blood-colors?rq=1)

This the closest thing I can remotely find that's even close to the color of gold. But I recommend giving up on a suitable answer cos it would take a alien creature or some other unknown substances to really make gold blood. Or you could take all that gold from Smaug, melt it and voila.

Comment: As colour, amber is already quite close to gold (Wikipedia gives #FFBF00 for amber and #FFD700 for gold). If you don't see a god actually bleeding, but only see the amber veins through the gods' skin, what you see would certainly be compatible with golden blood. Of course if you see a god bleeding, then you would additionally need to give it a metallic gloss. Note that the gloss-causing component need not be the same as the colour-giving component.

Comment: Our venous blood is a dark red, but it looks blue in our veins.  If venous blood were golden, it might look green in veins.  And of course in air, it would look uncolored or clear.  Perhaps Chloro-carbonyl-bis(tri phenylphosphine)-iridium would have fit better.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood#Hemovanadin)...

> The blood of some species of ascidians and tunicates, also known as
>   sea squirts, contains proteins called vanadins. These proteins are
>   based on vanadium, and give the creatures a concentration of vanadium
>   in their bodies 100 times higher than the surrounding sea water.
>   Unlike hemocyanin and hemoglobin, hemovanadin is not an oxygen
>   carrier. When exposed to oxygen, however, vanadins turn a mustard
>   yellow.

Comment: I cannot even tell if you are providing a single link or a complete bibliography. In both cases we prefer to have the content in the answer.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! This answer would be much better if you included the relevant information from the literature in your answer, instead of a single paragraph followed by a giant incomprehensible wall of references.

Comment: Welcome *res*! Please try to focus on the most important points to answer the question and write those points into your answer. Then you can and should link to where you got the information from for users who would like to know more about the topic. You just copied a lot of stuff and by looking at the links I can see that some are broken because of the formatting and other issues. It looks like you answered the question and so I am voting "Looks okay" (low-quality review queue). Please [edit] your answer, take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about how the site works. Have fun!

Comment: This answer is copied from something.  We need the original source cited and the content moved into a quote block.  Until then, this is a copyright violation.

Answer (score 2):

The gods blood was nano gold, gold particles that are no bigger than a virus. We as humans have nano iron running through our blood as a conductant for electric pulses to run throughout our bodies to sustain our energy, life, soul etc. this is how touch screens on your smart phone or any other touch devices are able to work. However, nano gold is an EXTREME super conductant unlike iron. When you take a strand of iron wire and put an electrical current in one end you will only recieve a smaller percent of that current out of the other end. Where as if you had an abundancy of nano gold (good luck) to be able to strech out no matter the distance from one end to the other, when you put a certain amount of electric currents in one end of the nano gold, on the other end you will recieve 100% of that same current. The gods were immortal because of this, their bodies held perfect energy that would sustain life forever with nano gold blood. 100% in 100% out. Yes the gods did have gold blood, they figured it out why cant we? Everything makes more since with a little knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

While you could look at it from a literal aspect (the blood is colored like gold), you could also look at it as a metaphor. In real life, there is "Golden Blood". Rh[null] blood is so rare, less than 45 people in the world have it and it can be used as a true universal donor, even for the people that O- blood normally can't help. I know you wanted the literal side of things, but I was beaten to that answer, so I hope this makes for a nice second best!