# What would be the implications of an ocean made from blood on the world?

Tags: climate, geography, ocean, water-bodies, blood

In my world of Ulhe rather than having saltwater between continents the oceans are filled with the blood of a god. Besides being blue the blood has similar physical properties to human blood. It is inhospitable to normal life except for a few genetically engineered types of sea life and large flats of algae and seaweed that sit on the surface. Lakes and rivers on land are normal freshwater that feed into the oceans. The environment is otherwise Earth-like with human-like people.

Would the blood eventually separate out into layers or would currents and the wind be enough to keep it mixed and if it didn’t mix would that leave a layer of freshwater as the surface?

Any thoughts on the effects or other comments would be welcomed.

Comment: blood + air = coagulated blood. Either that, or your god dies from a single paper cut.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand our standards. As it stands now your question is too broad, since it has multiple questions in it, while we enforce a "one post, one question" model.

Comment: "Besides being blue the blood has similar physical properties to human blood. It is inhospitable to normal life"  Why blue?  (Possibly see [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/28276/2113).)  Why inhospitable to normal sea life?  What happens to the salt from the freshwater?  (The small amount of salt in freshwater becomes concentrated by evaporation in salt water.)

Comment: The blood is blue for cosmetic reasons since it is part of the symbols of the gods the blood came from. The blood is has toxic components that kill ordinary freshwater animals and plants. I guess the salt and silt would settle down in the blood.

Comment: You need to give us a god idea of what the atmosphere is.

Comment: Normal Oxygen-Nitrogen atmosphere.

Comment: For starters, blood pudding would be less expensive.

Comment: My first thought is a lot of bacteria and disease, and eventually all the blood gets consumed by microbes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [this](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/02/130218092505.htm):

> Up until now it has been assumed that the special flow characteristics
>   exhibited by blood were mainly due to the presence of the red blood
>   cells, which account for about 45 percent of the blood's volume. Blood
>   plasma was generally regarded simply as a spectator that played no
>   active role. For decades, researchers have assumed that blood plasma
>   flows like water. After all, plasma, the liquid in which the blood
>   cells are suspended, consists to 92 percent of water. But results from
>   researchers at Saarland University and at the University of
>   Pennsylvania have now shown that plasma is a very special fluid that
>   plays a crucial part in determining how blood flows. The results
>   demonstrate that blood plasma is itself a non-Newtonian fluid.

As a non-Newtonian fluid, blood would certainly not behave like water.

The article is a fairly extensive study of the fluid dynamics of blood, but I think the critical part is that blood under high pressure (the bottom of the ocean) does not respond the way one would expect water to.

From the same article

> Experts refer to these materials as "non-Newtonian fluids," of which
>   ketchup and blood are prime examples. These fluids have flow
>   properties that change depending on conditions, with some becoming
>   more viscous, while others become less viscous. Blood (like ketchup)
>   is a "shear thinning fluid" that becomes less viscous with increasing
>   pressure and it is this that allows blood to flow into the narrowest
>   of capillaries. The flow properties of water are, in contrast,
>   essentially constant.

Think about an ocean full of ketchup.

Comment: An ocean of ketchup sounds unpleasant. I wonder if sailing ships would work better or worse with such a thick medium for the keel to pass through. Sailing ships might more easily skim over the surface with as little contact as possible.

Comment: @GiruSatuku if the viscosity has an inverse relationship with pressure, then the best way to move long distances through the ocean would be in a SUBMARINE. The deeper you go, the faster you can go with a given level of power output from whatever is moving you around. I don't think that sailing ships would work at ALL.

Comment: I am not sure you would get anywhere near the wave action that you would expect from water.

Comment: so, if you filled a cylinder with godsblood and put an astronaut in it..and pulsed rockets with an end to end rotation of the cylinder..what color gee would they beable to survive?

Comment: As an aside...damn that's fascinating :)